# Black screen on boot with blue cursor after reinstall

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, high-sierra

MBP 2017 with touchbar.

Brand new macbook, I upgraded to High Sierra and decided to try to reinstall macOS.

Now as *soon* as you touch the power button, it boots to this screen with fans at maximum:

[image: borked mbp]

Things I have tried:

- resetting NVRAM (doesn't seem to do anything?)
- resetting SMC
- turning it off and on

Comment: What steps did you take to downgrade back to Sierra? Did you try to install Sierra **on top** of the beta of High Sierra?  It's a bit difficult to tell from your question.

Comment: I tried to reinstall High Sierra using the recovery tool.

Comment: I have the same issue. No startup chime is present. Startup options like recovery and select startup disk take longer to start into. So far I haven't been able to resolve it, but am looking for solutions.